# How to standardize non-Gaussian residuals from ARMA-GARCH simulations?

Tags: r, residuals, garch, standardization, copula

I'm currently following the [example 6.2.3](http://copula.r-forge.r-project.org/book/06_misc.html) in Elements of Copula Modeling with R from Hofert et al (2018) to simulate the marginal residuals from a bivariate copula model. Now, I would like to simulate from marginal distributions different than the student-t. However, I'm not sure how to properly standardize the residuals from these distribution.

What they do, in the code right now is:

`eps. <- sapply(1:2, function(j) sqrt((nus[j]-2)/nus[j]) * qt(U.[,j], df = nus[j]))`

I understand that they're multiplying the inverse of the conditional variance but I don't understand the `qt()` part. I would like to know how to standardize the residuals if I go with a skewed normal (`snorm`), skewed student-t (`sstd`), and a Normal Inverse Gaussian (`nig`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code line you quote, they are probably transforming the uniform marginals `U.[,j]` as simulated from the copula into scaled Student-$t$ marginals `eps.` as are assumed by the ARIMA-GARCH model.

- `sqrt((nus[j]-2)/nus[j])` is the scaling part,
- `qt(U.[,j], df = nus[j])` is the part where a vector of simulated realizations from a uniform random variable from the copula is turned into a corresponding vector of Student-$t$ realizations.

If you want a marginal distribution other than the scaled Student-$t$, you would replace `qt` by a quantile function of another distribution (e.g. `qnorm` for normal). The scaling part would have to be applied if the distirbution has a non-unit variance, otherwise removed.